# i want to transmit data by byte unit and i think it's metter about endianness

Tags: c++, bit, endianness, memory-address, char-pointer

i want to transmit data by bit unit so i was access data with char* variable. here is my code.

```
int main()
{
    //initiate int variable and casting with char*
    int a = 65;
    cout << a << endl;
    char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    //check char* p is pointing &a
    cout << &a << endl;
    printf("0x%x\n", p);
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    //access int variable with byte unit
    cout << (int)*(p + 0) << endl;
    cout << (int)*(p + 1) << endl;
    cout << (int)*(p + 2) << endl;
    cout << (int)*(p + 3) << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    //initiate int variable and assemble with char* access in way 1
    int* b = new int(0);
    *b = *(p + 0) << 24;
    *b += *(p + 1) << 16;
    *b += *(p + 2) << 8;
    *b += *(p + 3);

    cout << *b << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    //initiate int variable and assemble with char* access in way 2
    *b = *(p + 0);
    *b += *(p + 1) << 8;
    *b += *(p + 2) << 16;
    *b += *(p + 3) << 24;

    cout << *b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and output like this.

```
65         -> variable a is 65
------------------
0x61ff04
0x61ff04   -> char* p is pointing right
------------------
65
0
0
0          -> access with byte unit
------------------
1090519040 -> way 1
------------------
65         -> way 2
```

when i access data by byte unit that first address pointing data shows '65' so i think this system is big endian.

so i thought if i want to transmit 'a' data to variable 'b', then *(p+0) data should be go to first like way 1, but the result isn't right. *(p+0) go at last - way 2, show right value.

in easy way to think, i think i was transmit data in direct memory point to point like this

```
variable a    =>    variable b
[0x000000]    =>    [0x100000]
[0x000001]    =>    [0x100001]
[0x000002]    =>    [0x100002]
    ...       =>       ...
```

i don't know why this happen. is anyone can explain about this?

============================================================================

problem was solved. the system was not big endian. i was mistake it.

Comment: `data by bit unit` - but you are printing bytes, not bits. It really looks like you would want to use [std::ostream::write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). I don't understand - explain what exactly? `why this happen` - what happens?

Comment: @KamilCuk you mean that you recommend to use ostream::write?

Comment: If you are sending the data across a wire, e.g. with a UART chip, that chip should sequence the bits on the wire properly for you, and present them properly to the recipient on the other end.  I suspect that you might be over-thinking this and "borrowing trouble."  Are you faced with an *actual* situation where the data *is* being received incorrectly?

Comment: `so i think this system is big endian` - Are you sure? The least significant byte (ie. `65`) is first. `you mean that you recommend` - I don't "recommend", I don't understand what are you doing and what do you want to do. I believe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah, your right. i was mistake. the system is little endian. thanks!

Comment: @MikeRobinson i'm consider about sending data to other system, but the situation is not correct. but in this problem, now i know what was wrong. thank you for your advise!

Comment: if you use a normal PC then 99.99% you're on a little endian system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i access data by byte unit that first address pointing data shows '65' so i think this system is big endian.

No, it means it is little endian. The least significant byte is in the lowest address and has the value 65.

With respect to 'transmitting' data between pointers of the same type by copying plain-old-data byte by byte, unless you are going between systems then endianness doesn't matter. It only matters in the interpretation, and `( *(p + 0) << 24 ) | ( *(p + 1) << 16 ) | ( *(p + 2) << 8 ) | *(p + 3)` is the big endian interpretation, so gives you the wrong result. You already know that `*p` is 65`*p` is 65, so even if you forget which way big or little means, `*(p + 0) << 24` will be wrong.

If you do want to transmit between systems byte-by-byte, there are the posix functions [`hton*X*()` and `ntoh*X*()`](https://minix1.woodhull.com/current/2.0.4/wwwman/man3/hton.3.html) which convert different integral types from host to network or from network to host byte order.

Comment: ah! thanks. i was mistake. system is little endian. now i know what was wrong.